# Subquery has too many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables with same structure: `tmp_grn` and `grn`.
I have to delete rows from table `tmp_grn` which already exists in table `grn`.
Problem is I don't have a unique or primary key but I can determine a unique row with the combination of two columns. Let's say column names are `grn_code` and `item_skucode`.

My query:

```
DELETE FROM tmp_grn 
  WHERE grn_code AND item_skucode IN 
    (SELECT grn_code , item_skucode FROM grn);
```

I am getting this error:

> ERROR:  subquery has too many columns

What should be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to combine two columns, you need to put them into parenthesis:

```
DELETE FROM tmp_grn 
  WHERE (grn_code, item_skucode) IN (SELECT grn_code, item_skucode 
                                     FROM grn);
```

But suslov's answer using an `exists` is most probably faster - you need to check the execution plan to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` (*if you want to check the pair of values*):

```
delete from tmp_grn t
where exists ( select * 
               from grn
               where grn_code = t.grn_code
                 and item_skucode = t.item_skucode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete * from tmp_grn intersect select * from grn
```